# Entity Framework overwriting custom properties

Tags: entity, partial-classes

1. In Entity framework, I have to add more properties to the auto generated properties in the Entity Framework. Is there is any way we can stop the EF to stop over writing these properties, when we regenerate the Entities.
2. In Entity Framework I am trying to override the auto generated entity by using partial class. But I am not able to get the scope of the new added properties in the base class, both the partial class are in same name space and has access Public.

Thanks Much.

Comment: Your #2 answers #1 :). Regarding #2, all partial classes must be in the same assembly. Also, partialing is not inheritance, all partials are *the same* class. There is no *base class* or *overriding*

Comment: 1.Is there is any other way to achieve this other than by question2.   2. Its in the same assembly. I should re-phrase, I am not inheriting, I am just trying to add more properties to the original partial class. When I try to refer to the new properties in my original partial class, it doesn't show up.